# How to convert csv to complex json

Tags: python, json, pandas

[image]

How to do this stuff in python pandas?
I am trying to make put request to some API and not sure how to generate request body since I have the csv file only . Request body asks for fixed set of schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataframe has a function `to_dict`.

```
documents = df.to_dict(orient='records')
result = {'items': documents}
```